# Is it possible to remove 'Contacts' from Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, search, contacts

Whenever I search for a program in Gnome Shell's search panel, some contacts from Pidgin will appear. E.g. when I search for `Chromium`, by typing `chr`, `Chris Andersen` will appear.  I don't want this to happen. Is it possible to disable this function?

Comment: Please define your question. For more details on best practices consider reading the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) on asking questions. Specifically is this related to Gnome-Do or what? Please describe. Regards,

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. It's not related to Gnome-Do. It's just normal gnome-shell behaviour. If you don't know what I'm talking about: `sudo apt get install pidgin gnome-shell`, then import contacts in Pidgin, after that, log in into a Gnome-Shell session, press the Super key, and start typing a name of one of your Pidgin contacts. His name will appear in the results. I don't want this to happen, the only thing I want to see is applications, directories and files.

Comment: Edited your question. "Gnome 3" is very ambiguous since there are two official Gnome 3 shells (the classic Gnome Panel and Gnome Shell) and several others, including Unity, which also has a "search panel".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious about this myself, greping around in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui` I found reference to `contactDisplay` in `overview.js`.  You should be able to comment out the two lines:

```
const ContactDisplay = imports.ui.contactDisplay;
this.addSearchProvider(new ContactDisplay.ContactSearchProvider());
```

and that will take care of it.  Just tested it, and nothing broke immediately (your results may vary).  I wont make any assumptions of your skill set so to comment these lines

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `gksu gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/overview.js`
find the two lines listed and place `//` (comment markers) in front of them, save, and Contacts are gone from search results.

The search panel you refer to is called the overview.  That may help with future questions.

Comment: Great, it works and it's an elegant solution, too. Thanks for telling me how to comment in a `.js` file, because I was already going with the `#`s :-P

Comment: A more elegant solution would be an extension that removed it, because if gnome-shell updates than you will have to go back in and do it again.  Maybe I'll work on that.  One of the annoying things I find about the contacts is duplicates from different programs.

Comment: I try this, but never found the lines :(

Answer (score 4):

Go to: Settings | Search | Contacts | OFF

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing (using Gnome Shell 3.10.4) the contacts search provider (`gnome-contacts-search-provider`) is added by the `gnome-contacts` package:

```
> locate gnome-contacts-search-provider
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/gnome-contacts-search-provider.ini

> apt-file search /usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/gnome-contacts-search-provider.ini
gnome-contacts: /usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/gnome-contacts-search-provider.ini
```

If you don't use the Contacts app you can remove it and the search provider with it.

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-contacts
```

Answer (score -1):

It is by default search handling technique in gnome , better way is to use synapse for search, it is very light and very fast, plus it provides filters to search. it will solve your problem,

Comment: Or add a launcher for chromium so you so not need to search for it all the time ;)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for.